# Close multiple box-dropdowns on outside click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

There are multiple dropdowns, in this case three (but could be any number), which have toggleable dropdowns. However, if you click on all of them, they will all remain opened. How could I make it close when the other one is activated, and when there's an outside click?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pcm2w3ov/1/

```js
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    button.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("dropdown-visible");
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    box 1
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box 2
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box 3
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two parts to the problem. To toggle the current dropdown whilst hiding the others you can select them all and use `filter()` to exclude the current dropdown whilst hiding all the others.

To hide all the dropdowns when the click occurs outside the `button` or `.dropdown` elements you can bind an event handler to the `document` which checks the event to see from where it originated. Then you can either ignore the event, if the user clicked on a button or dropdown, or hide all dropdowns if the user clicked outside of those elements.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

// toggle dropdowns
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let targetDropdown = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  Array.from(dropdowns).filter(dd => dd != targetDropdown).forEach(dd => dd.classList.remove('dropdown-visible'));
  targetDropdown.classList.toggle('dropdown-visible');
}));

// hide dropdowns when click occurs on external element
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('dropdown') || e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON')
    return;
    
  dropdowns.forEach(dd => dd.classList.remove('dropdown-visible'));
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    box 1
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box 2
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box 3
    <button>toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```